# I know DotNetNuke there for some time, how about using LightSwitch and DotNetNuke to build apps in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, visual-studio-lightswitch

need your views, pros and cons, for linear data entry forms kind of application.

Some of them described here

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/29/Easy-DotNetNuke-LightSwitch-Deployment.aspx

Is it a overkill to use both these as combine? :)

Because i see two other views.

1.Lightswitch does not natively generate ASP .net UI but have great next layers

2.DotNuke has good UI portion

Answer (score 0):

Michael Washington has actually done a lot with Lightswitch and DotNetNuke.  I would begin by checking out his community Lightswitch site here: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/